# Unable to export users from openerp to otrs

Tags: odoo, otrs

I want to export users from `OpenERP` to `OTRS`. I am new in `OTRS` and don't know how to do this.
Is there any module in openerp. I am working on `OpenERP 6.1`.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking two different questions: how to get your data out of OpenERP and how to get your data into OTRS.

As far as I know there are no pre-defined connectors for this.
If you're talking about what OTRS calls 'customer' records, you can set up a database connection to let OTRS look directly in OpenERP. 
If you don't want to keep openERP data but want to migrate to OTRS, you can import the data from a CSV file or the like, using the Cape IT [CustomerImportExport](http://opar.perl-services.de/package/C/CA/CAPEIT/CustomerUserImportExport) module, for instance.